# Yeoman, npm install errors registry

Tags: npm, office-js, excel-addins

When trying the Excel Addin Tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-jquery?tabs=yeomangenerator) I get an error when running npm start :

```
> office-addin-taskpane-js@0.0.1 start D:\sheet_organizer
> office-addin-debugging start manifest.xml

Debugging is being started...
App type: desktop
Enabled debugging for add-in sheet_organizer. Debug method: 0
Starting the dev server... (webpack-dev-server --mode development)
The dev server is running on port 3000. Process id: 8456
Sideloading the Office Add-in...
Error: Unable to start debugging.
Error: Unable to sideload the Office Add-in.
Error: Unable to delete registry value "D:\sheet_organizer\manifest.xml" in key "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\Developer".
ProcessUncleanExitError: DELETE command exited with code 1:

Error: can't find the key or the value
```

I check manually the key. There is a Developper>05c2e1c9-3e1d-406e-9a91-e9ac64854143 folder

With UseDirectDebugger, UseLiveReload and UseWebDebugger

So the key exist. Don't understand why it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this issue was fixed. OfficeDev/Office-Addin-Scripts#215

Please get the latest version of office-addin-debugging.

There are a couple of ways to do this.

1-  npm update --dev can update all packages according to semver. (You can see outdated packages using npm outdated --long.)

2-   You could update office-addin-debugging package using npm install -D office-addin-debugging.

Ref:https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/issues/1321

Comment: Work fine! Thank you